# Finding the average of a column excluding certain rows using AWK

Tags: linux, bash, awk, scripting

I want to calculate the average of the 5th column (last column) excluding the rows with the value "9999". Would appreciate your feedback.

> ```
> 77.300 16 1 3.6112914285714268 9.4 
> 77.300 16 2 -0.001737142857145102 20.0 
> 77.300 16 3 5.1570742857142857 8.9 
> 77.300 17 0 3.6112914285714268 8.9  
> 77.300 17 1 2.9484342857142849 11.7  
> 77.300 17 2 -0.001737142857145102 22.6   
> 77.300 17 3 3.5098971428571417 9.2 
> 77.300 18 0 3.5098971428571417 9.4  
> 77.300 18 1 2.9484342857142849 14.0  
> 77.300 18 2 -0.001737142857145102 24.7   
> 77.300 18 3 3.5098971428571417 9.4  
> 77.650 13 0 3.2896914285714267 9.4  
> 77.650 13 1 0.0042514285714272404 24.9 
> 77.650 13 2 2.0769371428571421 9.1  
> 77.650 13 3 0.0042514285714272404 99999  
> 77.650 14 0 1.8255085714285713 9.3  
> 77.650 14 1 0.0042514285714272404 99999 
> 77.650 14 2 1.8255085714285713 9.2  
> 77.650 14 3 0.0042514285714272404 99999  
> 77.650 15 0 3.2896914285714267 8.7  
> 77.650 15 1 4.2542171428571418 8.7
> ```

Comment: since you are using [awk] as a tag, you may have some knowledge about it. Post your attempts so that we can help you finish the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through awk,

```
$ awk '$5!="99999"{sum+=$5}END{print sum}' file
227.5
```

Explanation:

- `$5!="99999"` if 5th column does not contain `99999`, then do
- `{sum+=$5}` adding the value of 5th column to the variable `sum`. Likewise it keeps adding the value of 5th column when awk see's the record which satisfies the given condition.
- Finally print the variable `sum` at the end.

For average.

```
$ awk '$5!="99999"{sum+=$5;cnt++}END{print (cnt?sum/cnt:"NaN")}' file
12.6389
```